# Integrating jquery-ui and jquery validation

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using jquery ui controls, and jquery validation plugin.

let's say I want to add a required class on a combobox.

The element is dynamically generated with a generic code.

Where can I add the class ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, the combo box is generated after the user does some action and then you want to add a CSS class to that combo box?  Or are you just trying to add a class to a combo box?

Comment: I'm just trying to add css class on an element jq-ui generates when document loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to select the next brother with the proper classes:

```
$('#someSelect ~ .ui-autocomplete-input').addClass('bla');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add this html to your view.  Or take out the script tags and add this to your js file for that page.  In the case below I am adding two classes to the combobox.

This combo box:

```
<select id="cbCars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

This is the JQuery wrapped in a html script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#cbCars").addClass("ui-state-active ui-corner-top");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No your'e not, you are adding the class to the hidden select that works as the data source of the combobox jq ui generates